# Count distinct while aggregating others?

Tags: java, apache-spark, streaming

This is how my dataset looks like:

```
+---------+------------+-----------------+
|  name   |request_type| request_group_id|
+---------+------------+-----------------+
|Michael  |     X      |  1020           |
|Michael  |     X      |  1018           |
|Joe      |     Y      |  1018           |
|Sam      |     X      |  1018           |
|Michael  |     Y      |  1021           |
|Sam      |     X      |  1030           |
|Elizabeth|     Y      |  1035           |
+---------+------------+-----------------+
```

I want to calculate the amount of `request_type`'s per person and count **unique** `request_group_id`'s

Result should be following:

```
+---------+--------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------+
|  name   |cnt(request_type(X))| cnt(request_type(Y))| cnt(distinct(request_group_id))|
+---------+--------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------+
|Michael  |          2         |         1           |      3                         |
|Joe      |          0         |         1           |      1                         |
|Sam      |          2         |         0           |      2                         |
|John     |          1         |         0           |      1                         |
|Elizabeth|          0         |         1           |      1                         |
+---------+--------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------+
```

What I've done so far: (helps to derive first two columns)

```
msgDataFrame.select(NAME, REQUEST_TYPE)
            .groupBy(NAME)
            .pivot(REQUEST_TYPE, Lists.newArrayList(X, Y))
            .agg(functions.count(REQUEST_TYPE))
            .show();
```

How to count distinct `request_group_id`'s in this select? Is it possible to do within it?

I think it's possible only via two datasets join (my current result + separate aggregation by distinct `request_group_id`)

Comment: functions.countDistinct ?

Comment: @pasha701 if we supplement current aggregation with this function - it will count unique group id per `X` and `Y` counts, so simple further summation won't solve the initial problem. 
I want to perform this distinct group id counting per `NAME`...

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example with "countDistinct" ("countDistinct" is not worked over window, replaced with "size","collect_set"):

```
val groupIdWindow = Window.partitionBy("name")
df.select($"name", $"request_type",
      size(collect_set("request_group_id").over(groupIdWindow)).alias("countDistinct"))
  .groupBy("name", "countDistinct")
  .pivot($"request_type", Seq("X", "Y"))
  .agg(count("request_type"))
  .show(false)
```